# Difference between timestamps value while creating and querying the Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having issues with the timestamps on the Sequelize models. When creating a new record via the model, the `createdAt` timestamp contains milliseconds, but when I query the database using `findOne()`, it doesn't contain milliseconds. The `createdAt` column in the database is of type `timestamp`.

- Value while creating model: `2018-12-04T07:18:14.075Z`
- Value while retrieving model via query: `2018-12-04T07:18:14.000Z`

Anyone know what to do? Why is this even inconsistent?

I'm using Sequelize `4.41.2`.

Comment: are you trying to manually set `createdAt`?

Comment: You can add `timestamp` attributes, such as `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and `deletedAt`, in your model definition and pass `defaultValue: () => new Date(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))`.

By default sequelize create default value for `timestamps` attributes with ms, but store it without. When sequelize insert new row, it doesn't receive inserted values from db.